# How do I create an rssfeed from the contents on this page?

Tags: rss, http-api

So. I created a gmail rss feed with php that I placed in a custom page. I used this snippet:

```
 function checkGmail($username, $password)
 { 
 $url = "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom"; 

 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
 $mailData = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);

 return $mailData;
 }

 header('Content-Type:text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
 $feed = checkGmail("mail@gmail.com", "password");
 echo $feed;
```

And it outputs the xml on my site. Great. Then I tried to create a validated feed from this, and this is where Im stucked. I tried to create a custom rss feed by this:

```
 add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_rss_template' );
/**
* Register custom RSS template.
*/
function my_rss_template() {
add_feed( 'short', 'my_custom_rss_render' );
}

/**
* Custom RSS template callback.
*/
function my_custom_rss_render() {
get_template_part( 'feed', 'short' );
}
```

Then I tried to call it all by http://website.com/?feed=feed-short but It says something in the lines of not a valid feedtemplate. It does output the xml on the custom page if I navigate to it by it´s slug. So what do I do here?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at

```
ABSPATH . WPINC . 'feed-*.*';
```

to see examples. WP core has feed tempaltes for the following protocols:

- Atom
- RDF
- RSS
- RSS2

When writing a plugin, you can take the following quick test plugin as base. It adds a feed name `custom-feed` to the list of feeds.

```
<?php 
/* Plugin Name: (WPSE) #172796 Custom Feed */

add_action( 'init', function()
{
    add_feed( 'custom-feed', function()
    {
        /** @var \WP_Query $wp_query */
        global $wp_query;

        // Custom conditions when to output the feed - and when not
        if ( 'foo' !== get_query_var( 'name' ) )
            return;

        load_template( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'templates/feed-rss2.php' );
    } );
} );
```

To get a quick look at the default feeds, simply dump them

```
var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->feeds );
```

When you activate above test plugin, you should find `custom-feed` as last entry in the array.

Inside any callbacks you should check if you are actually working on the new custom feed:

```
$wp_query->is_feed( [ 'custom-feed', ] );
```

To get a valid feed, you will have to set a `header`. Core does it like the following:

```
header( sprintf( 
    'Content-Type: %s; charset=%s',
    feed_content_type( 'rss-http' ),
    get_option( 'blog_charset' )
), true );
```

Then there's the actual XML opening tag:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'.get_option('blog_charset').'"?'.'>';
```

after that, there's a place to allow plugins to hook in:

```
do_action( 'rss_tag_pre', 'rss2' );
```

Finally there is the `<rss version="2.0" ...` tag opening and another hook to add custom namespaces

```
do_action( 'rss2_ns' );
```

The list goes on and on. The best you can do is to take the core files as blueprint for your own feeds (copy/paste them to your plugin and alter the output).